# How can i scroll menu to current item in menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have menu that contains 11 elements. 3 of it are displayed. There are buttons like a slider, that helps scrolling this menu. On my site i give special class to element, when its href == url of page(highlighting of current element). I need to move this current element in the first left position of menu on window load, so menu list must be scrolled, when page is loading, and current element stays in the first left place regardless position in list. 
So that's my code:

```js
function slideR() {
  $('#menu > ul > li').first().css('left', '300px').appendTo('#menu > ul').animate({
    "left": "-=300px"
  }, 200);
}

function slideL() {
  $('#menu > ul > li').last().animate({
    "left": "+=300px"
  }, 200, function() {
    $(this).prependTo('#menu > ul').css('left', '0px');
  });
}

$('.arrow-right').click(function() {
  slideR();
});
$('.arrow-left').click(function() {
  slideL();
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
nav > ul {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 0;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
}
nav > ul > li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
nav > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.arrows > .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.arrow-right {
  right: 0;
}
.arrow-left {
  left: 0;
}
.active a {
  color: #029A55;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 8</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 9</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 10</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 11</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrows">
    <span class="arrow arrow-right"></span>
    <span class="arrow arrow-left"></span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Please help me to supplement my code to solve the problem.
I try this

```js
var curry = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
$(window).load(function() {
  curry.style.left = '0px';
});
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: Somebody helps me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do a loop of `slideR` until the first child has the `active` class by adding the `firstLoad` function, like in this updated snippet.

```js
firstLoad();
function firstLoad() {
  while(!$('#menu > ul > li').first().hasClass("active")) {
    slideR();
  }
}

function slideR() {
  $('#menu > ul > li').first().css('left', '300px').appendTo('#menu > ul').animate({
    "left": "-=300px"
  }, 200);
}

function slideL() {
  $('#menu > ul > li').last().animate({
    "left": "+=300px"
  }, 200, function() {
    $(this).prependTo('#menu > ul').css('left', '0px');
  });
}

$('.arrow-right').click(function() {
  slideR();
});
$('.arrow-left').click(function() {
  slideL();
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
nav > ul {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 0;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
}
nav > ul > li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
nav > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.arrows > .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.arrow-right {
  right: 0;
}
.arrow-left {
  left: 0;
}
.active a {
  color: #029A55;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 8</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 9</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 10</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 11</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrows">
    <span class="arrow arrow-right"></span>
    <span class="arrow arrow-left"></span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: There is a problem... i give class active on window load, and page doesn't load with your code. Only when i add class active in php, so static, your code works. How can i solve it?

Comment: @Alex just move the function caller `firstLoad();` to below or right after you give the `active` class